# SQLite3 Python 2.7 sqlite3.OperationalError syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
import codecs

sqlite3.connect("test.db")
db.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STATIONS
       (StationUID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
       StationNumber           TEXT    NOT NULL,
       StationName             TEXT    NOT NULL,
       StationLongitude        REAL    NOT NULL,
       StationAltitude         REAL    NOT NULL);""")

print "Created Table STATIONS successfully"
cr = db.cursor()
name = "b"
station_number = "0123"
longitude = 13.4
altitude = 34.4
cr.execute("INSERT INTO STATIONS VALUES", (None, station_number, name, longitude, altitude))
db.commit()
```

It throws `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "VALUES": syntax error`, but I don't understand why, because it is the same syntax I found in the example.

Comment: `cr.execute("INSERT INTO STATIONS VALUES (None, station_number, name, longitude, altitude)")`

Comment: this is not right this are variables not the column names.

Comment: @Anmol_uppal: no, because then you are mixing Python literals and variable names into the SQL syntax. That's not going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify *what values to insert*:

```sql
INSERT INTO STATIONS VALUES (value1, value2, ...)
```

You cannot omit that part. Use SQL parameters to map Python values to those locations in the SQL syntax:

```
cr.execute(
    "INSERT INTO STATIONS VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    (None, station_number, name, longitude, altitude))
```

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_insert_query.htm it says that You may not need to specify the column(s) name in the SQLite query if you are adding values for all the columns of the table.

Comment: @quesaionasis: yes, if you are inserting values for fewer columns than the table defines. Your table has 5 columns, you are inserting 5 values, so there is no need to specify the column names here. You can drop the initial  `None` column (translated to NULL in SQLite) if you specify the other 4 column names.

Comment: ´cr.execute("INSERT INTO STATIONS VALUES (StationNumber, StationName, StationLongitude, StationAltitude)", (station_number, name, longitude, altitude))´ this leads to sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: StationNumber

Comment: @quesaionasis: see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html, the names go *before* the `VALUES` text.

Comment: ahh there was the error i have mistaken (?,?,?,?) for the column names

Answer (score 1):

The `INSERT` command is not complete.  You need to insert the values into the `INSERT` by writing:

```
cr.execute("INSERT INTO STATIONS VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (None, station_number, name, longitude, altitude))
```